# Authorization based on roles

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards, angular-auth-oidc-client

Is there a way to easily handle authorization based on roles with the lib angular-auth-oidc-client?

As soon as a user is on the site, I want to identify them, so I use the `auto-login-all-routes` guards, and this far everything is ok for me. But I'd like to allow access only if the userData contains a specific role, otherwise redirect to the unauthorized page.

At first I though I could just create a custom version of auto-login-all-routes.guard.ts but as most of the services used are not exported by the module, it doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 guards.

First one to authenticate:

```
auto-login-all-routes.guard
```

Then a custom guard to listen `oidcSecurityService.userData$` and check for roles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I'm currently using, not sure if it is what you are looking for.

**Routes**

```
{
  path: 'import',
  component: ImportComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard, RoleGuard],
  data: { roles: new Set([UserRole.admin, UserRole.developer]) },
},
```

**Guard**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private location: Location) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.store.select(selectUserRoles).pipe(
      debounce((roles) => (roles ? EMPTY : timer(2500))),
      map((roles) => {
        const permittedRoles = (route.data as RouteData).roles;
        if (
          roles &&
          Array.from(roles.values()).some((role) => permittedRoles.has(role))
        ) {
          return true;
        } else {
          alert(
            `Requires one of the following roles: ${Array.from(permittedRoles)
              .map((role) => getRoleName(role))
              .join(', ')}`
          );
          this.location.back();
          return false;
        }
      }),
      first()
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as per documentation
https://nice-hill-002425310.azurestaticapps.net/docs/documentation/auto-login

[image]

---

it's not recommended to use `AutoLoginAllRoutesGuard` so I used `AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard`

### Example

in `app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { AutoLoginAllRoutesGuard, AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';

const routes: Routes = [
// ...

{ path: 'add-permit', component: AddPermitComponent, canActivate: [AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard] },

// ...
]
```

Comment: I'm not able to combine two guards here,
like when I'm doing this way

            canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard, AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard]

it is not working as expected

Comment: @ManishPatidar try AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard first  `[AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard, AuthenticationGuard]`